# EF Core 5.0 Ignore Default PK

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

For example I have the following tables:

```
Class Customer
{
   public string UserId { get; set;}
   public string CustomerId { get; set;}
}
```

How can I specify that the PK is UserId and not the CustomerId?

Even though I specify the entity key like this, EF still assumes that CustomerId is PK:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.UserId)
                    .HasName(...);
...
```

Apparently, there should be mentioned somehow to EF to ignore CustomerId.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: It is always a good idea to name PK as Id. CustomerId  and UserId should be the foreign keys and EF doesn't assume anything if you don't mark property as a Key

Comment: If you think that you need to ignore CustomerId as PK you then will need to ignore all properties of any class as well.